# R Shiny - observe () The date input is also triggered when the value of dataInput is not changed

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have shiny code that generates inputs and each of those Inputs trigger the observe when the value is changed, however this does not happen in the dateInput, the dateInput is triggered before the observe.

I want the dateInput to be triggered only when the value of date is changed.

Here is the code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

js <- "
$(document).on('change', '.dynamicSI .selector select', function(){
Shiny.setInputValue('lastSelectId', this.id, {priority: 'event'});
});
$(document).on('change', '.dynamicSI .radio input', function(){
Shiny.setInputValue('lastSelectId', $(this).attr('name'), {priority: 'event'});
});
$(document).on('change', '.dynamicSI .input input', function(){
Shiny.setInputValue('lastSelectId', this.id, {priority: 'event'});
});

$(document).on('change', '.dynamicSI .date input', function(){
Shiny.setInputValue('lastSelectId', $(this).parent().attr('id'), {priority: 'event'});
});
"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$script(HTML(js))),       

    numericInput("graph_tytle_num", "Number of Graph Title elements", 
                 value = 1, min = 1, max = 10),
    uiOutput("graph_title"),
    plotOutput("plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #elements of graphic titles  
  output$graph_title <- renderUI({
    buttons <- as.list(1:input$graph_tytle_num)
    div(class = "dynamicSI",
        lapply(buttons, function(i)
          column(
            width = 3,
            div(class = "selector",
                selectInput(inputId = paste0("title1_element",i),
                            label = paste("Title element",i),
                            choices = paste0(LETTERS[i],seq(1,i*2)),
                            selected = 1)
            ),
            div(class = "radio",
                radioButtons(inputId = paste0("title2_element",i),
                             label = paste("Title1 element",i),
                             choices = c("Yes","No"),
                             selected = "Yes")
            ),
            div(class = "input",
                numericInput(inputId = paste0("title3_element",i),
                             label = paste("Title element",i),value=1)
            ),
            div(class = "date",
                dateInput(inputId = paste0("title4_element",i),
                          label = paste("Title element",i),
                          value = "1900-01-01")
            )
          )
        )
    )
  })

  # react to changes in dynamically generated selectInput's
  observeEvent(input$lastSelectId, {

    cat("lastSelectId:", input$lastSelectId, "\n")
    cat("Selection:", input[[input$lastSelectId]], "\n\n")

    title <- c()
    for(i in 1:input[["graph_tytle_num"]]){
      title <- paste(title,input[[paste0("title1_element",i)]],input[[paste0("title2_element",i)]],
                     input[[paste0("title3_element",i)]],input[[paste0("title4_element",i)]])
    }

    output$plot <-renderPlot({hist(rnorm(100,4,1),
                                   breaks = 10,
                                   main = title)})

  })  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you for the help. Much Appreciated